# How to know the one selected row in the tabs containing the datagridview

Tags: c#

I have a project with a form with 3 tabs, each contains 1 datagridview. I disabled multiselect and can only select a row.

I need to Add new data rows or Modify rows of datas from these three datagrids, so I have a MenuStrip on top of the window with a menu with a "Add", "Modify" and "Delete Selected Row" options.

How do I know which row is currently being selected in the current selected tab containing the datagrid which contains that row? Because there are 3 tabs containing 3 datagrids. I don't want to get the output saying there are 3 datagridviews selected with whatever row was selecting. I want the one row on my screen.

Please ask me if my question isn't clear enough.

Comment: Which frontend technology are you using?

Comment: When a DataGrid loses focus, i.e, you switch tabs, when you switch back again, does it retain its selected row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that this question is about `WinForms`. Below there's a schematic code logic sample for clicking a `ToolStripMenuItem` named `Show selected row` belonging to a `MenuStrip` on the form. Just adapt the method logic to your `Modify` and `Delete` buttons `click` events.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    dataGridView1.DataSource = new[] { new { Id = 1 }, new { Id = 10 } };
    dataGridView2.DataSource = new[] { new { Id = 2 }, new { Id = 20 } };
    dataGridView3.DataSource = new[] { new { Id = 3 }, new { Id = 30 } };
}

private void showSelectedRowToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dgv = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.OfType<DataGridView>().FirstOrDefault();
    if(dgv != null)
    {
        if (dgv.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            // I'm using MessageBox to show the index of the row. 
            // You should add your Modify / Delete logic
            MessageBox.Show(dgv.SelectedRows[0].Index.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

For the .NET Framework 2.0, you can find the selected tab's first `DataGridView` control, if existing, like this:

```
DataGridView dgv = null;
for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[i].GetType() == typeof(DataGridView))
    {
        dgv = (DataGridView)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: how I can check `tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.ofType' in framework 2.0

Comment: @vikas, this question was posted with the [tag:c#] tag. So [tag:vb.net] is out of scope. You can try to convert the code by yourself and if you really can't manage it, there are a few online conversion tools such as [http://converter.telerik.com/](http://converter.telerik.com/) which could help you.

Comment: If I add the code after InitializeComponents(), it wouldn't work! The other 2 dgvs woouldn't display anything except the id columns, but the code works fine without that code.

Comment: In my answer, I'm not handling any complex data source binding, I just added some simple data sources to make the demo work. So, I assigned data sources with only one column (`Id`) to each `DataGridView`. I believe you already handle the data binding, so you can delete the `dataGridViewN.DataSource = ...` from the `Form1` constructor, after the `InitializeComponent();` call.

Answer (score 1):

Check on click
Suppose Tab Control is tabCtrlReports and Tab name is tbUser then check condition

```
 If (tabCtrlReports.SelectedTab.Name = "tbUser") Then
// your code of grid
End If
```

In C# just

```
if (tabCtrlReports.SelectedTab.Name = "tbUser") 
{
    // your code of grid
}
```

Comment: It's not `VB.NET`, but `C#` :)

Answer (score 0):

In your post back event(s), perhaps check which tab is selected (if statement, case statement) and then take a the specific action to modify your data and page accordingly.

If you want to call another VS generated post back function for the datagrid, you'll have to pass in your parameters correctly - I believe the source should be the row object from your datagrid.

Another option could be to modify your data, re-query, and bind the results to the appropriate grid (rather than trying to use grid events).

Answer (score 0):

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name == "Name1") 
{
     row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
}
else
{
    if (tabControl1.SelectedTab.Name == "Name2") 
    {
        row = dataGridView2.CurrentRow;
    }
    else
    {
        row = dataGridView3.CurrentRow;
    }

if (row != null)
{
    //your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

an approach which does not depend on datagridview's names:

```
   var rtb = ((DataGridView)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Cast<Control>()
                  .FirstOrDefault(x => x is DataGridView)).CurrentRow;
```

(a test to verify that the tabpage has a datagridview might be added )